# Trigger Multiple JUnit Tests in multiple directories

Tags: java, maven, junit

Is there any command, which can trigger JUnit tests in multiple directories?
Imagine I got a parentfolder which contains two maven projects `Foo` and `Bar`.

In `Foo` and in `Bar` I can trigger the tests with `mvn test`.
Is it possible to trigger both tests with one command? Like `mvn ....`?

Any collectors for the tests?

Answer (score 2):

Imagine you have the following project structure:

[image: http://imgur.com/zEtHo3f]

- You can trigger the tests in the `foo` project with `mvn test` in the `foo` directory.
- You can trigger the tests in the `bar` project with `mvn test` in the `bar` directory.
- You can trigger the tests in the `foo` and `bar` projects with `mvn test` in the `foobar` directory.

`foo` and `bar` must be `<module>`s of the `foobar` project.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any other way? With "mvn -f foo/pom.xml test" you would Trigger the Foo's Test, if you re in the parentdirectory "Foobar". On that why there is no any parent pom.xml reuquired. Do you know if there any Parameter enabling you giving multiple pom.xml?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know any other way to achieve this goal without aggregate the two projects